Movie with a teen blue bald alien and a boy and girl helping her with something
I am looking for a movie... I think. I only saw some part of it as a kid. Don't know what country made it.
I remember this teen blue bald alien with three fingers and some scenes of a boy and a girl helping her with something. I remember a bit of a scene with some huge creature guarding the door to the alien ship behind a waterfall? And kids helping the alien to distract that creature. That's about it.

This is The Boy from Andromeda (1991).

According to the Wikipedia page, it's a six-part New Zealand miniseries that was aired in Canada as as single film.
In prehistoric times, aliens from Andromeda used Earth as an outpost in a war with another alien race. The war ended long ago, but the Andromedans left behind some of their technology, including a powerful gun beneath a volcano and a soldier robot called the Guardian (a Predator knock-off), which resides in a lake.
In modern times, a ten-year-old Andromedan boy named Drom is passing by Earth in his spaceship when it is shot down by the Guardian, which has been programmed to attack any spacecraft approaching the planet. The Guardian also wants the Fire Key, a pyramid-shaped device on Drom's ship, which can destroy it.
Drom splits the Fire Key up into three sections which are found and discovered by three human teenagers, Jenny, Tessa and Lloyd. Through the Fire Key, they establish communication with Drom and ultimately help him to stop the Guardian.
Drom is bald and has blue skin and three fingers on each hand, He is played by a young actress with an older male voice dubbed in.



